# Locating content on page with nested(?) anchor tags?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Asume that my website is domain.com, with a store page, domain.com/store
By adding `id = "itemid"` to every item I can let users visit the item directly by:

```
domain.com/store#itemid
```

Usual anchor behavior. However, I need something a little more complex.

Assume that my item hierarchy is as follows:

```
<div id="item1>
   <div class="images"></div>
</div>
```

I want the user to directly reach the "images" box of the given item by using an anchor-like addressing. Such as

```
domain.com/store#itemid.images
```

What's the best approach for this?

Comment: if you are only using the default browser behavior, I would use `#itemid_image` (imply to add an id for all images)

Comment: it's only an example, my initial content has many dynamic sub-elements - which could be hard to manage. The functionality I'm looking for is close to allowing users link any section of the page.

Comment: So than every section must have ID's (!unique!)

Comment: hm okay, I was hoping for a better solution :(

Comment: Giving a unique id to each element in your page is not a lesser solution.  I would also encourage you to do that.  However, it sounds a bit like you want to give a url for a group of items in your page ("domain.com/store#itemid.image***s***").  As far as I know, that is not doable.  You can however give a link to domain.com/store#item01_image01.  And that is very acceptable

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, split the hash into two parts: id and class then use then using javascript or jquery find that element and scroll it into view.

```
hash = window.location.hash.split('.')
document.getElementById(hash[0]).getElementsByClassName(hash[1])[0].scrollIntoView(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try naming the subdivs with the item id?

Something like

```
<div id="item1>
   <div class="item1_images"></div>
   <div class="item1_ex"></div>
</div>
```

So then, you can use domain.com/store#itemid1_images